# Android SQLite Update doesnt update the record

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have an issue with updating an SQLite DB. I want to mark a record as read when a record is accessed by updating a field called "burstRead" to 1. When the record is created, I set the field to 0 (which signifies it is unread). The code when creating the table and adding the records are below:

```
// burst Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "burstID";
private static final String KEY_ACCTNAME = "acctName";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "burstDate";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "burstTitle";
private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "burstDescription";
private static final String KEY_CONTACT = "burstContact";
private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "burstAddress";
private static final String KEY_REMINDER = "burstReminder";
private static final String KEY_READ = "burstRead";
private static final String KEY_IMG = "burstImg";
private static final String KEY_FILE = "burstFile";
private static final String KEY_ID = "burstID";
private static final String KEY_ACCTNAME = "acctName";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "burstDate";
private static final String KEY_TITLE = "burstTitle";
private static final String KEY_DESCRIPTION = "burstDescription";
private static final String KEY_CONTACT = "burstContact";
private static final String KEY_ADDRESS = "burstAddress";
private static final String KEY_REMINDER = "burstReminder";
private static final String KEY_READ = "burstRead";
private static final String KEY_IMG = "burstImg";
private static final String KEY_FILE = "burstFile";

String CREATE_BURSTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_BURSTS + "("
            + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_ACCTNAME + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_DATE + " TEXT," + KEY_TITLE + " TEXT," + KEY_DESCRIPTION
            + " TEXT," + KEY_IMG + " TEXT," + KEY_CONTACT + " TEXT,"
            + KEY_ADDRESS + " TEXT," + KEY_REMINDER + " TEXT," + KEY_FILE
            + " TEXT," + KEY_READ + " INTEGER)";
db.execSQL(CREATE_BURSTS_TABLE);

// Adding new contact
public void addBurst(Burst burst) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(KEY_ID, burst.getBurstID()); // Burst ID
    values.put(KEY_ACCTNAME, burst.getAcctName()); // Burst Account Name
    values.put(KEY_DATE, burst.getBurstDate()); // Burst Date
    values.put(KEY_TITLE, burst.getBurstTitle()); // Burst Title
    values.put(KEY_DESCRIPTION, burst.getBurstDescription()); // Burst Description
    values.put(KEY_CONTACT, burst.getBurstContact()); // Burst Contact
    values.put(KEY_ADDRESS, burst.getBurstAddress()); // Burst Address
    values.put(KEY_REMINDER, burst.getBurstReminder()); // Burst Reminder
    values.put(KEY_IMG, burst.getBurstImg()); // Burst Image
    values.put(KEY_FILE, burst.getBurstFile()); // Burst File
    values.put(KEY_READ, 0); // Burst Read

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(TABLE_BURSTS, null, values);
    db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

**values.put(KEY_READ, 0);** I believe this is one correct way to set the field to zero when inserting the record.

The update script is as follows:

```
public void updateBurstRead(int burstID) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_READ, 1);

db.update(TABLE_BURSTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?", new String[] { String.valueOf(burstID) });
db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
```

How the app works is that the MainActivity.java consists of a listview that when clicked launches an intent called DetailActivity.java, bundling the burstID so that the content of the Burst can be viewed in the new activity. At this point the function updateBurstRead() should execute and update burstRead to 1.

This is how I am calling and updating the necessary functions and variables in DetailActivity.java

```
Burst data = new Burst();
private int burstID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
    // Show the Up button in the action bar.
    setupActionBar();

    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    burstID = b.getInt("burstID");
    data = db.getBurst(burstID);

    db.updateBurstRead(burstID);
...
```

I know that the updateBurstRead function is being called and executed without any errors but the record is not being updated.

So what could be the problem?

Comment: nothing in `logcat`? have you check value returned by `update`>

Comment: I am getting a return value of 1

Comment: I am also checking the value of burstRead after the update but it stays at zero (0).